# Repast HPC in Xcode 5.1 parse issue error

Tags: c++, xcode, repast-hpc

all.

I’d like to ask a question about the error I encounter when I try to use Repast HPC in Xcode 5.1.
(Repast HPC is an agent-based simulation library based on C++. For more information, go to http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_hpc.html)

For testing, I tried to build and run the Repast HPC Tutorial Demo code from tutorial page(http://repast.sourceforge.net/hpc_tutorial/RepastHPC_Demo_00_Step_05.html). 
I succeeded to run Demo00 Step 04, which seems to mean that my preference setting is correct, but failed to run Demo00 Step 05. The major difference between those two is “RepastProcess.h” is included in Step 05.

The error occurs in 50th line of “logger.h” file, which is included "RepastProcess.h". The line of error is,

**typedef enum _LogLevel {DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL} LOG_LEVEL;**

The error is 'parse issue error' and the message says "Expected '}'" and the location of error seems to be 'DEBUG' because there is a tiny triangle under the word. 
I googled a lot, but I couldn’t find any issue in the code. 
Does anybody face similar error? Is it the problem of Xcode setting?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: More than likely, DEBUG is already defined as `#define DEBUG` or on some compiler switch `-DDEBUG`. If that is the case, that clause reduces to : `typedef enum _LogLevel{,INFO,...}` after preprocessing, which is most-assuredly wrong. Pretty poor planning on their part to use an enum with a name that is such a common preprocessor macro.